# How to implement the toolbar of tableau public in tableau server in publish workbook in embed view?

Tags: tableau-api

I want to user or replace the tool bar tableau public into tableau server?
Actually my requirement was to view current view without use of Remember my Changes in embed view.

I don't want this below view of share in which only link of parent page is provided. A different link is to be automatically generated when view or any parameter is changed in embed view.

[This is the basic preview of Tableau server share option but I want to replace with below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixIkj.png). Instead of this above view I want the below options in my published workbook. [This is the preview of tableau public we want in tableau server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMP2E.png) I want the current view like above picture in my tableau server.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible (not without hacking the Javascript of Tableau Server, which would be unsupported).

I would suggest that you create a support case, and ask for an enhancement request for the option to change the Tableau Server share menu.